# How do I validate a form where the data comes from 2 inputs?

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

Case in question: Date and time. My form has 2 separate `input` fields, `date` (opens a date picker) and `timeOfDay` (opens a clock picker),

```
<div class="form-group date-and-time">
    <div class="my-datepicker md-form-control">
        <md-input readOnly type="text" placeholder="Date" myDatePicker formControlName="date">

        </md-input>
        <small *ngIf="!form.controls.date.valid && submitted" class="ui error-message">
            Invalid date.
        </small>
    </div>
    <div class="my-clockpicker md-form-control">
        <md-input readOnly type="text" placeholder="Time" myClockPicker formControlName="timeOfDay">

            <span md-suffix>'Clock</span>
        </md-input>
        <small *ngIf="!form.controls.timeOfDay.valid && submitted" class="ui error-message">
            Invalid time.
        </small>
    </div>
</div>
```

and

```
private _initForm() {
    let now = moment();
    this.submitted = false;
    this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
        date: [now.format('DD.MM.YYYY'), [<any>Validators.required]],
        timeOfDay: [now.format('HH:mm'), [<any>Validators.required]],
        ...
    })
}
```

I need to make sure that the user can't enter a date and time that is in the future, but I can only validate one input at a time, which, of course, is not going to work. How do I go about this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create a custom validator that would accept the other control as input. Something like this:

```
 export class CustomValidators { 

     static futureDated(
        thePassedInControl: AbstractControl) {
        return function (theValidatedControl) {
            return new Promise(resolve => {

            var futureDated = false;
            //determine which control is date, and which is time   
            //determine if future dated
            //...

            if (futuredated) {

                resolve({ 'futureDated': true });
            }
            else {
                resolve(null);
            }
        });
        };
    };
}
```

You can then use this validator on both controls:

```
this.date = new FormControl(now.format('DD.MM.YYYY'), <any>Validators.required);
this.timeOfDay = new FormControl(now.format('HH:mm'), <any>Validators.required);         

//set custom validators
this.date.setAsyncValidators(CustomValidators.futureDated(this.timeOfDay));
this.timeOfDay.setAsyncValidators(CustomValidators.futureDated(this.date));

this.form = this.formBuilder.group({
            date: this.date,
            timeOfDay: this.timeOfDay,
            ...
        })
```